# Java : Error on build

Tags: java, netbeans

I made an application in *Java with Netbeans*, but when I wanted to export it *(build)* an error message is displayed :

> C:\Users\DALY\Documents\NetBeansProjects\VacheTaureau\nbproject\build-impl.xml:926: The following error occurred while executing this line:
>   C:\Users\DALY\Documents\NetBeansProjects\VacheTaureau\nbproject\build-impl.xml:268: Class not found: javac1.8
>   BUILD FAILED (total time: 1 second)

here is a screen print

[image: Screenshot of error]

Comment: Uh, it couldn't find the xml file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes my friends, I found the solution to this problem!
In fact I downloaded Apatch Ant (TM) version 1.96 and it works!

here's the ant link
 [Apatch Ant V 1.96](https://ant.apache.org/bindownload.cgi)

Description:
We must extract the file 'apache-ant-1.9.6-bin.zip' downloaded to folder and you must put this folder under the following path :

C: \ Program Files (x86) \ NetBeans 7.3.1 \ java.
Then in NetBeans, go to the menu:

Tools> Options> Java
then you must change the way Ant home of the folder ( 'apache-ant-1.9.6-bin').

print Screen
[image]